# how to insert data into a table that has a foreign key?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables :

```
                 usine 
======================================
id_usine | nom_usine | referance_usine
```

and for every `usine` we have `ligneproduction` so I have an other table :

```
  ligneproduction
=================== 
id | nom | fkUsine
```

I added an item in table using this:

```
INSERT INTO `USINE` (`id_usine`, `nom_usine`, `referance_usine`)
             VALUES ('3', 'LAFARGE BISKRA', 'LAFARGE_BISKRA');
```

I want to add a "ligne production" in `ligneproduction` table corresponding to that item in usine table.

How can I do that?

Comment: Do you use autoincrement columns? If not: "INSERT INTO `ligneproduction` (`id`, `nom`, `fkUsine`) VALUES (1, 'Ligne 1', 3);"

Comment: This doesn't work ! fkusine is a foreign key from usine (id_usine)

Comment: Why wouldn't it work. Id_usine is 3.

Comment: maybe because it's a String, so try to use '3'

Comment: i did that : INSERT INTO `LIGNEPRODUCTION` (id , nom , fkusine) VALUES ('5','Ligne Gris 1 Biskra', '3');
and it didn't work

Comment: Do this : `INSERT INTO LIGNEPRODUCTION (id , nom , fkusine) VALUES (5,'Ligne Gris 1 Biskra', 3);`, id are int and `'5' and '3'` are strings. Tell me if it works :)

Answer (score 0):

Use this ...set last inserted id and insert into child table and make ligneproduction's id is auto incremented

```
INSERT INTO `USINE` (`id_usine`, `nom_usine`, `referance_usine`)
                 VALUES ('3', 'LAFARGE BISKRA', 'LAFARGE_BISKRA');

    SET @id_usine = (SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID());

    INSERT INTO `ligneproduction` (`nom`, `fkUsine`)
                 VALUES ('any value depends on u', @id_usine);
```